Kepler gl Uncaught runtime errors using Draw On Map>Polygon tool and Draw On Map>Rectangle tool:
Kepler gl Uncaught runtime errors using Draw On Map>Polygon tool and Draw On Map>Rectangle tool:
I'm receiving these errors when using the Kepler.gl>Draw On Map>Polygon tool and Draw On Map>Rectangle tool.
I think this might related to babel or webpack?
**Here's my import for creating the store. **
``
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk';
import { taskMiddleware } from 'react-palm/tasks';
import { keplerGlReducer } from '@kepler.gl/reducers';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
``


``
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
(0 , _rewind.default) is not a function
TypeError: (0 , _rewind.default) is not a function
    at DrawPolygonMode.rewindPolygon (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:155146:39)
    at DrawPolygonMode.getAddFeatureAction (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:155160:32)
    at DrawPolygonMode.getAddFeatureOrBooleanPolygonAction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:155251:19)
    at DrawPolygonMode.handleClick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:153250:31)
    at EditableGeoJsonLayer.onLayerClick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:161248:28)
    at EditableGeoJsonLayer._onanyclick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:162032:12)
    at EditableGeoJsonLayer._forwardEventToCurrentLayer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:162022:7)
    at EventRegistrar._emit (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:344192:9)
    at EventRegistrar.handleEvent (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:344090:12)
    at Manager.emit (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:311400:20)
``

``
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
(0 , _bboxPolygon.default) is not a function
TypeError: (0 , _bboxPolygon.default) is not a function
    at DrawRectangleMode.getTwoClickPolygon (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:199052:51)
    at DrawRectangleMode.getGuides (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:205182:26)
    at DrawRectangleMode.getTentativeGuide (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:200606:25)
    at DrawRectangleMode.checkAndFinishPolygon (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:205147:35)
    at DrawRectangleMode.handleClick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:205121:12)
    at EditableGeoJsonLayer.onLayerClick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:206738:28)
    at EditableGeoJsonLayer._onanyclick (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:207522:12)
    at EditableGeoJsonLayer._forwardEventToCurrentLayer (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:207512:7)
    at EventRegistrar._emit (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:320708:9)
    at EventRegistrar.handleEvent (localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:320606:12)
``

My package.json:
``
{
  "name": "kepler-gl-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "ajv": "^8.16.0",
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "kepler.gl": "^3.0.0",
    "@luma.gl/core": "^8.5.20",
    "@luma.gl/webgl": "^8.5.20",
    "@deck.gl/core": "^8.9.27",
    "@deck.gl/extensions": "^8.9.27",
    "@deck.gl/layers": "^8.9.27",
    "@deck.gl/react": "^8.9.27",
    "@deck.gl/mapbox": "^8.9.27",
    "@nebula.gl/layers": "1.0.2",
    "@nebula.gl/edit-modes": "1.0.2",
    "@nebula.gl/editor": "1.0.2",
    "@nebula.gl/overlays": "1.0.2",
    "@loaders.gl/polyfills": "^4.1.0-alpha.4",
    "react-vis": "^1.11.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-palm": "^3.3.8",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.5",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },

  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
``

Here's the bundle.js showing the (0, _bboxPolygon["default"]):
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", ({
      value: true
    }));
    exports.DrawRectangleMode = void 0;
    var _bboxPolygon = _interopRequireDefault(__webpack_require__(/*! @turf/bbox-polygon */ "./node_modules/@turf/bbox-polygon/dist/cjs/index.cjs"));
    var _twoClickPolygonMode = __webpack_require__(/*! ./two-click-polygon-mode */ "./node_modules/@kepler.gl/layers/node_modules/@nebula.gl/edit-modes/dist-es6/lib/two-click-polygon-mode.js");
    function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
      return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {
        "default": obj
      };
    }
    function _typeof(obj) {
      "@babel/helpers - typeof";

      if (typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol") {
        _typeof = function _typeof(obj) {
          return typeof obj;
        };
      } else {
        _typeof = function _typeof(obj) {
          return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj;
        };
      }
      return _typeof(obj);
    }
    function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
      if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
        throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
      }
    }
    function _defineProperties(target, props) {
      for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        var descriptor = props[i];
        descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
        descriptor.configurable = true;
        if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
        Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
      }
    }
    function _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
      if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
      if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
      return Constructor;
    }
    function _createSuper(Derived) {
      return function () {
        var Super = _getPrototypeOf(Derived),
          result;
        if (_isNativeReflectConstruct()) {
          var NewTarget = _getPrototypeOf(this).constructor;
          result = Reflect.construct(Super, arguments, NewTarget);
        } else {
          result = Super.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, result);
      };
    }
    function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) {
      if (call && (_typeof(call) === "object" || typeof call === "function")) {
        return call;
      }
      return _assertThisInitialized(self);
    }
    function _assertThisInitialized(self) {
      if (self === void 0) {
        throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called");
      }
      return self;
    }
    function _isNativeReflectConstruct() {
      if (typeof Reflect === "undefined" || !Reflect.construct) return false;
      if (Reflect.construct.sham) return false;
      if (typeof Proxy === "function") return true;
      try {
        Date.prototype.toString.call(Reflect.construct(Date, [], function () {}));
        return true;
      } catch (e) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    function _getPrototypeOf(o) {
      _getPrototypeOf = Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.getPrototypeOf : function _getPrototypeOf(o) {
        return o.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(o);
      };
      return _getPrototypeOf(o);
    }
    function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
      if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) {
        throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function");
      }
      subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
        constructor: {
          value: subClass,
          writable: true,
          configurable: true
        }
      });
      if (superClass) _setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass);
    }
    function _setPrototypeOf(o, p) {
      _setPrototypeOf = Object.setPrototypeOf || function _setPrototypeOf(o, p) {
        o.__proto__ = p;
        return o;
      };
      return _setPrototypeOf(o, p);
    }
    var DrawRectangleMode = /*#__PURE__*/function (_TwoClickPolygonMode) {
      _inherits(DrawRectangleMode, _TwoClickPolygonMode);
      var _super = _createSuper(DrawRectangleMode);
      function DrawRectangleMode() {
        _classCallCheck(this, DrawRectangleMode);
        return _super.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      _createClass(DrawRectangleMode, [{
        key: "getTwoClickPolygon",
        value: function getTwoClickPolygon(coord1, coord2, modeConfig) {
          var rectangle = (0, _bboxPolygon["default"])([coord1[0], coord1[1], coord2[0], coord2[1]]);
          rectangle.properties = rectangle.properties || {};
          rectangle.properties.shape = 'Rectangle'; // @ts-ignore

          return rectangle;
        }
      }]);
      return DrawRectangleMode;
    }(_twoClickPolygonMode.TwoClickPolygonMode);
    exports.DrawRectangleMode = DrawRectangleMode;

I expect the Draw On Map>Polygon tool and Draw On Map>Rectangle tool to draw on the map with no errors.
